# Copy file from Google Cloud Bucket to Local folder

Tags: r, linux, google-cloud-platform

I use this command in Rstudio to see the last file from a list

`system("gsutil ls gs://Bucket_Dir/** | tail -n 2 | tail -n 1 ")`

How can I copy that file to the local directory?

thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will want to use the *cp* command:

```
 gsutil cp gs://bucket/folder .
```

More info about gsutil can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil). You can replace the '.' with a local folder you want to download to.

**Edit:** This would result in: 
`gsutil cp "$(gsutil ls gs://bucket/** | tail -n 2 | tail -n 1)" .` for your use case.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong?: system("gsutil cp ls gs://Bucket_Dir/** | tail -n 2 | tail -n 1 .")  because it doesn't work

Comment: **Edited comment to not include path info**. You use either cp or ls. You can read the docs on what does what exactly. You can either specify the filename in the command, or use something like this: `gsutil cp "$(gsutil ls gs://bucket/** | tail -n 2 | tail -n 1)" .`